# Subtotal of duplicate items in cell mentioning the duplicate items the last time

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, automation

Currently, I am using the sum function to total matching item names by manually selecting matching cells. I would appreciate help automating the calculation of subtotals by item name.

[Link to my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tX8WryiGivXMuadWAbQm3y3EyaPulbNLyNPRUcOo_WU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Copy of [Duplicate items in a range to be added in separate column](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/211158656).

Comment: See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Answer (score 0):

##### Formula in `E14`

```
=SUM(FILTER($C$2:D14,$A$2:A14=A14))
```

Copy and paste the formula down the range `E15:E21`

[image]

##### Single cell formula

Uses the QUERY function to generate a new table with all the item subtotals as well as a grand total row.

```
=LET(subs, QUERY(A2:D21,
       "select A, SUM(C) + SUM(D) group by A
       Label A 'Item Name', SUM(C) + SUM(D)'Subtotal'"),
     { subs; 
       "==================", "=======";
       "Total:", SUM(INDEX(subs,,2)) })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This formula will match your recently changed desired results:

```
=let( 
  header, "Subtotal per item", table, A2:E, items, A2:A, 
  data, arrayformula(if(isblank(items), "", if(isblank(table), 0, table))), 
  totals, query(data, "select Col1, sum(Col2) + sum(Col4) group by Col1", 0), 
  rowNumbers, sequence(rows(items), 1, row(items)), 
  lookupTotal_, lambda(i, vlookup(i, totals, columns(totals), false)), 
  lastOccurrenceRow_, lambda(i, xlookup(i, items, rowNumbers, , -1, -1)), 
  result_, lambda(i, if(row(i) = lastOccurrenceRow_(i), lookupTotal_(i), iferror(1/0))), 
  { header; map(items, result_) } 
)
```

See [let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535) and [lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718).

Comment: But regarding your solution i have a query i have edited the formula as per my requirement but i am getting a error message .
But i am getting error in my new Work sheet :- 

Error message says :- 

Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC.

Comment: That is a different question that will require a different solution. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead, and [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)